# How do I Search an Array of Strings for specific Substring and Drop / Remove / Delete those Array Items that contain that Substring using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, search, lodash

There are a ton of great questions/ answers related to searching / looping through an Array of Strings and matching a given Substring but I couldn't readily find a **concise example that uses Lodash to delete / remove any array element that DOES include the desired search substring**.

The best resource I found for searching / matching against an array of strings is this question (several good answers): [Use lodash to find substring from array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615413/use-lodash-to-find-substring-from-array-of-strings)

> None of those answers appeared to be readily applicable to immediately removing the item IF it matched (true) against the search / substring.

Is there an easy way to loop through an array of strings and delete items that match using Lodash?

*While other options are on the table we would ideally want to use Lodash since we already depend on this for many similar functions.*

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finding a way to use Lodash's _.remove function to accomplish this as follows:

```
        // The String (SubString) we want to match against array (for dropping purposes)
        var searchSubString = "whatever" 

        // Remove all array items that contain the text "whatever"
        _.remove(my_array, function(searchSubString) {
              return n.indexOf(searchSubString) !== -1;
            });
```

Basically indexOf is matching against the position of the substring within the string, if the substring is not found it will return -1, when indexOf returns a number other than -1 (the number is the SubString position in number of characters within the Array string) Lodash removes that item via Array mutation.

References:
[Lodash _.remove documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove)